# How to override a file located in Main theme sub folder and override it in child theme

Tags: wordpress

In my main theme, I have a file I need to edit
**main-theme/inc/widgets/activates/widget-active.php**

Problem: How can I edit/override the widget-active.php in my child-theme?

I tried creating the same folder structure in my child theme but it doesn't work, tried searching for solutions but didn't saw what I was looking for.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Maybe the theme doesn't support child theme fully like `Travelify`

Comment: I'm using Listify by Astoundify